# PHP page does not change after reload

Tags: php, ajax, refresh

I have a PHP application in which I can delete some registers after I start a session on it.

When I select the rows I want to delete (via checkbox) I click the delete botton and the rows are deleted successfully.  (well, the rows are not deleted really, they just change state to 'deleted'). The problem is that if I reload the page, the registers that I deleted show up again.

To make sure I wont see again the deleted rows, I have to close session and start it again.

By the way, Im usign ajax to do the delete operation. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you are storing the initial SQL results in your session, and populating the form from that.  If you are doing something like that clear the session data after performing the delete operation.